# Is there a prayer or something I can do to see Allah or to hear His Voice in my dream?

Tags: allah

I want to ask you one thing about how can I see God Almighty directly and what should I do in order to see Him?  Because this was always my wish to see Him directly and talk with Him.  I believe He can do anything, and to Him it's piece of cake, like 1-1=0 or easier than this.

Is there any prayer or a thing that I should do in order to see Him directly in my vision just like He shows Himself to people of Paradise? I’m asking this because, I was thinking that if we cannot see Him this world with eyes open, then maybe in our vision, while we sleep. “Because”, there is something that I’m really stressed about and I cannot know wether is a good or a bad wish. And I’m not really sure wether He is agreed with my wish or not. Or, if He does not want to show Himself then, to hear His Voice, and I’m really curious to know what is His decision, if He is agreed or not with my wish. “Because”, I’d like to hear at least His magnificent and beautiful Voice for one time and then second time in Paradise.

I do not want to give myself as an important thing to Him, because He did not chose me as an important person like Muhammad, Muhammad, probably: yes, He could have chance to see Him, but as for me, no, because I’m not important as he, not only me, none of us is important, but simple species who tries to fulfill the duties which He Made for us. And besides, I’m very afraid because I don’t know at all, what is His decision, if He is agreed To fulfill that wish, because to me is something beneficial that wish. Actually, I’m trying to say is, that I’m not putting myself to the level of prophet, simply because I’m not a prophet, just a regular person. I would be sooo grateful and happy if I would hear at least His Voice.

Comment: Whatever you see in your dream it is not God, since nothing is like him.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can't see Allah, exalted He is in this Life. And this is the ultimate reward that believers will get in Paradise, i.e Seeing Him.

Recall the story of Moses, pbuh, when he requested to see Allah. The Al Mighty responded that Moses won't be able to see Him.

**Verse 7:143**

> And when Moses arrived at Our appointed time and his Lord spoke to
>   him, he said, "My Lord, show me [Yourself] that I may look at You." [
>   Allah ] said, "You will not see Me, but look at the mountain; if it
>   should remain in place, then you will see Me." But when his Lord
>   appeared to the mountain, He rendered it level, and Moses fell
>   unconscious. And when he awoke, he said, "Exalted are You! I have
>   repented to You, and I am the first of the believers."

**Why can't I ?**

There is a great wisdom behind this, and we can list many reasons we can think of(guess):

Seeing Allah would influence faith? i.e some people will think they didn't choose by intellect and faith, but He imposes himself upon them by showing himself to them.

Can our sight handle His glory? mountain couldn't, neither our sight.

If Allah is just and He'd reveal Himself to someone, then to be fair He must give an equal chance to non-believers as well to see Him!!

and many more reasons.

Finally we reply with what Allah has decided for people not to be able see Him in this life. recall for your reference :

**Verse 42:51**

> وَمَا كَانَ لِبَشَرٍ أَن يُكَلِّمَهُ اللَّهُ إِلَّا وَحْيًا أَوْ مِن
>   وَرَاءِ حِجَابٍ أَوْ يُرْسِلَ رَسُولًا فَيُوحِيَ بِإِذْنِهِ مَا
>   يَشَاءُ ۚ إِنَّهُ عَلِيٌّ حَكِيمٌ - 42:51
>
> And it is not for any human being that Allah should speak to him
>   except by revelation or from behind a partition or that He sends a
>   messenger to reveal, by His permission, what He wills. Indeed, He is
>   Most High and Wise.

**I love Him.. I really want to see Him:**

Here is your answer, if you are truthful then you should taste the sweetness of His Love through Iman, and following Him:

**Verse 3:31**

> Say, [O Muhammad], "If you should love Allah, then follow me, [so]
>   Allah will love you and forgive your sins. And Allah is Forgiving
>   and Merciful."
>
> قُلْ إِن كُنتُمْ تُحِبُّونَ اللَّهَ فَاتَّبِعُونِي يُحْبِبْكُمُ
>   اللَّهُ وَيَغْفِرْ لَكُمْ ذُنُوبَكُمْ ۗ وَاللَّهُ غَفُورٌ رَّحِيمٌ -
>   3:31

And Allah knows best.

Comment: Why would this influence faith? God is the most powerful and Al-Controller, right? So, if He wish He can Make in such that He will not influence faith even if some of us will see Him in dream, right?

Comment: Yes He can,  check sura 10 verse 99. We're not questioning His ability here. The vision is a different story as this is a personal experience Allah grants to someone.. It has no effect on others, and if He shows this to a specific person, then surely that person deserved to see Him!

Comment: Aaaa, I think I understand now

Comment: `forgive you your sins.` First of all thanks for the great post and I do wonder, forgive you your sins, is the grammar suppose to be like this or did you make a minor small mistake?

Comment: @VolkanGüven  the translation is Saheeh international’s version and yes this is a grammatical error. May Allah reward you bro. I will fix it.

Answer (score 1):

How can a limited human being see the Limitless. How can a human being who depends on the material world to see, see the One who is not material?

We will never be able to see Allah swt with our eyes, but as Ali b. Abi Talib stated:

> "Eyes do not see Him face to face, but hearts perceive Him through the
>   realities of belief."

```
Nahjul Balagha, Sermon 177
```

There is a beautiful video clip about this sermon, when Dhi'lib al Yamani asked Amir al Mumineen whether he dad seen Allah swt. He replied, "Do I worship one whom I have not seen? Dhi'lib asked, "How have you seen Him?" Ali b. Abi Talib replied with this [sermon](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rk-PCLkKPyg).

Comment: Is Nahjul Balagha,Sermon 177 a name of video?

Comment: No , Nahjul Balagha, which can be translated as "Peak of Eloquence" is a collection of letters, sermons and sayings of Ali ibn Abi Talib and was compiled more than 1000 years ago by Sayed Radhi.

Answer (score 0):

As Salam Aleikhum brother Allah is Supreme  you know that his presence is everywhere  everything on heaven and earth belong to Him.If your prayer is sincere his messenger Isha(peace be upon him ) may reveal himself to you in your dream by the will of Allah and neither you or I have seen Allah I believe in Allah.

Comment: Allah revealed himself to prophet  Musa (peace be upon him  ) through the burning bush the bush on fire but Prophet Musa (peace be upon him ) did not know how Allah looked like.

Comment: So if I wish that God Almighty will show Himself in my dream just like He shows Himself and to have also to talk to Him,and to tell Him my feelings just as He shows Himself to believers in Heaven,then I must pray and my prayer should be very sincere?question of curiosity.